# Экспорт из Зеплин и Фигма

Tags: вёрстка, figma

Как можно извлечь, как-то сохранить макет из Зеплин и Фигма, именно сам макет для перфект пиксель.
Еще вопрос про извлечение картинок, иконок тд из макета! При извлечении как можно указать папку? а не сразу качать в "Загрузки", касается и Зеплин и Фигма

Comment: Настроить браузер, чтобы он спрашивал куда сохранять, а не качал сразу в "Загрузки". Для разных браузеров это настраивается по-разному.

Comment: ага, спасибо, а на счет экспорта для перфект как?

Comment: Без понятия, не в курсе что это